# would selecting on too many fields cause a table lock?

Tags: sql-server, database, scalability

I have a SELECT statement in a stored procedure that under very heavy load results in a timeout: "Lock request time out period exceeded." - at least that's what .NET throws. It is a pretty simple query on a table (CODES) that has a primary key and a clustered index (on TYPE_CODE1). The only thing that looks out of the ordinary is that there are many fields being selected on (all the fields except Dclass are bit fields). Would this cause the lock on the table? Any other ideas?

TIA
T

```
select
@TYPE_CODE1 = TYPE_CODE1,
@ALTERNATE_CODE = ALTERNATE_CODE,
@BANNER = BANNER,
@CODE_1 = CODE_1,
@CODE_2 = CODE_2,
@CODE_3 = CODE_3,
@CODE_4 = CODE_4,
from CODES with (nolock)
where
Dclass = @Dclass
and Ret = @Ret
and Rem = @Rem
and Ope = @Ope
and Res = @Res
and Cer = @Cer
and Cdo = @Cdo
and Del = @Del
and Sig = @Sig
and Ads = @Ads
and Adr = @Adr
and Emi = @Emi
and In1 = @In1
and In2 = @In2
and Paa = @Paa
and Reg = @Reg
and Red = @Red
and Rer = @Rer
and Ree = @Ree
and Rei = @Rei
and Spe = @Spe
and Mer = @Mer
and Hol = @Hol
and Day = @Day
and Sca = @Sca
and Sis = @Sis
and Poa = @Poa
and Haz = @Haz
and Sun = @Sun
and Out = @Out
and IsActive = 1
```

Comment: Throwing the NOLOCK hint at the problem is NOT a good approach. That is dealing with the symptom instead of the problem and the impact can be far greater than dirty reads. http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Comment: This error message does not sound like data locks. Post the full exception ToString and make sure that it is this statement that is causing the error.

Comment: How big is the table? (Number of rows X size in bytes of row would be good to know.) Your where clause means every time this is run, you are getting a table scan.

Comment: In all likelihood this is a schema locking problem.

Comment: @PhilipKelley there are only `ANDS`s in the `WHERE` clause, so it won't cause a table scan unless there's no appropriate index for the query.

Comment: @usr It's frustrating, but that's the only error message I have in the logs.

Comment: @RBarryYoung I'm 100% sure that the data is static.

Comment: @PhilipKelley The table is approx 600 rows with data that never changes. It should really be cached, but currently it's not. The whole data for the table is about 104KB.

Comment: How do you know it's this statement? I cannot think of a reason this statement would ever cause this message. Given that the table is static is really shouldn't cause this message.

Comment: @RBarry, given that there are about 30 columns specified in the where clause, it is a reasonable assumption that they are not all covered by indexes. However, at only 104KB, time to scan the whole table cannot be the issue.

Answer (score 3):

`Lock Request Timeout exceeded` doesn't always directly correlate to a table lock.  That error means that the query was waiting to obtain a lock on an object in SQL server but couldn't do it fast enough, so the query timed out.

Additionally, SQL uses a process called `lock escalation` where, if a query requires more than 5000 locks (page/row level locks), it will request a full table lock.  If you are reaching this 5000 lock threshold and trying to take a table lock out, it could be getting stuck behind some other process that already has a lock on it.

I'd try running your application and then, at the same time in management studio, use a tool like sp_Whoisactive and find out what's blocking your application and causing it to timeout.  Odds are some other process has a lock on the table you are trying to query.

Comment: Thanks Kris. It's still a mystery. We're pretty sure we don't have any other process that's accessing this table, definitely not for inserts and updates. These lockout issues happen in bursts so it's not easy to throw in Management Studio to help especially since we're talking Production server. We have about 100 transactions per second in Production hitting this SP at the same time so we're nowhere near the 5000 limit. I really wish we found out the cause, but we will probably cache this so we can move on.

Answer (score -1):

SELECT statements that use the NOLOCK hint on any table they access never cause locks or wait for them. So it shouldn't be this statement that caused the error.

Comment: Not True.  All actual queries require *some* locks.  Generally read-access database and schema locks at a minimum, IIRC.

Comment: True enough, but what existing locks would block a query with `noclock`? (I *never* use nolock, and so am unfamiliar with the low-level details.)

Comment: Makes sense... and it seems pretty unlikely that that's what's going on here.